# Why do Entity classes must have an @Id?

Tags: jpa, entity, primary-key

I am a little confused about that. When I try to create an entity that without @Id, the compile-time gives me an error that I must set primary key use @Id, and I even can't deploy the application to the application server (I use payara). But the requirement for entity classes in the official Java EE 7 tutorial documentation doesn't contain the rule that an entity must have @Id. And, the definition of an entity in that documentation:

> Typically, an entity represents a table in a relational database, and each entity instance corresponds to a row in that table.

But I can create a data-table that without primary key.

So my question is actually that why do we must set @Id in an entity. Are there any other considerations? For example, use the @Id to identify a specific entity in persistence context, so that we can use em.find(id)? And what should I do if I insist on creating an entity without @Id, lol.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA Entity beans are required to specify a primary key one way or the other.

From the *JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.1 Specification*,

> **2.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity**:
>
> Every entity must have a primary key.
>
> The primary key must be defined on the entity class that is the root of the entity hierarchy or on a mapped superclass that is a (direct or indirect) superclass of all entity classes in the entity hierarchy. The primary key must be defined exactly once in an entity hierarchy.
>
> A primary key corresponds to one or more fields or properties (“attributes”) of the entity class.
> ...

Answer (score 1):

An entity is something you store in a database (i can't come up with a use case where you don't do this). Something you store in a database table needs to have a primary key. For a primary key, we generally use Id.

I'm pretty sure the warning you're receiving is some added 'are you sure you've not forgotten something?' functionality by the IDE, and can be disabled in the settings.

Comment: But when I run the application, the runtime also gives me the error..lol.

Comment: @MarcuX when do you get the error? When you're storing the entity in the database? If so, have you actually defined another property as the primary key?

Comment: Just when I deploy the application on the payara server

Comment: @MarcuX which method is throwing the exception? Please share your entity definition.

Comment: No...I haven't invoked any method...just when I deploy the application, it throws the error..so I mean, the deployment is not succeeded.lol.

Answer (score 0):

If I talk about database, every table should have some column (or columns) that 
can uniquely identifies a particular row.

In a same manner, as our entity class represents a table, so **@Id** is immensely required there.

(My answer is just a hint for those, who are beginners.)